# How to delete a question from within the iphone app?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I accidentally posted a question in the wrong site. I tried to delete from iPhone app, but I can not find the way.

Comment: You can't. The apps use SE API, which does not support deletion. Use a browser to delete the post.